# Cookies was not sent when the request come from front-end

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, session-cookies, apollo-server

I am following [Ben Awad full stack tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6ypD7qv3Z8&t=11470s) with same stack (

- React
- TypeScript
- GraphQL
- URQL/Apollo
- Node.js
- PostgreSQL
- MikroORM/TypeORM
- Redis
- Next.js
- TypeGraphQL
- Chakra
- )
  But newer versions (the video was 2 years old), in 2:59:59, according to the video, when we make a register request through browser(client side) the qid cookies was supposed to get sent automatically but it doesn't work for me. ***Things work fine when I make request through my server (localhost port 5000, redirect to https://studio.apollographql.com/sandbox/explorer) but when it come to browser I successfullyy register the user but the cookies was not saved.***

Here is the code I built in my server to set the cookies (redis connected):

```
   app.use(
cors({
  origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "https://studio.apollographql.com"],
  credentials: true,
})
```

)

```
app.set("trust proxy", true);

app.use(
  session({
    name: "qid",
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient, disableTouch: true }),
    cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10, //10 years
    httpOnly: false,
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true, // cookie only works in https
  },
  saveUninitialized: false,
  secret: "123456789",
  resave: false,
 })
);
```

Thanks guys and I appreciate you guys a lot.

Comment: You can check if cookies are blocked on your browser or not. If you're using Chrome, you can follow this guide: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61416?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Answer (score 1):

I solved it: set `sameSite: 'none'` when you want to save `cookie` through `sandbox` and `lax` when you want to save it with browser.